# Python Keyword Argument extra word

Tags: python

A very easy Python code. I wish to obtain the following:

```
>>> sandwich('wheat')
 'wheat bread sandwich with turkey'
>>> sandwich('white', meat='ham', cheese='American')
 'white bread sandwich with ham and American cheese'
>>> sandwich('white', cheese='American', meat='ham')
'white bread sandwich with ham and American cheese'
>>> sandwich('rye','ham','Swiss')
 'rye bread sandwich with ham and Swiss cheese'
>>> sandwich('white', cheese='provolone')
 'white bread sandwich with turkey and provolone cheese'
```

This is my code. I want to ignore any cheese in my first sentence. How do i do that?

```
>>> def sandwich(bread, meat='turkey', cheese=None):
>>>     print bread,"bread sandwich with",meat,"and",cheese,"cheese"


>>> sandwich('wheat')
>>> sandwich('white', meat='ham', cheese='American')
>>> sandwich('white', cheese='American', meat='ham')
>>> sandwich('rye','ham','Swiss')
>>> sandwich('white', cheese='provolone')
```

This is my code. I want to ignore any cheese in my first sentence. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this

```
def sandwich(bread, meat='turkey', cheese=None):
    if cheese:
        print bread,"bread sandwich with",meat,"and",cheese,"cheese"
    else:
        print bread,"bread sandwich with",meat
```

If cheese is not passed, it gets the default value None from function definition. Based on that, you can decide print sentence with cheese.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the default value from `None` to `""` (empty string) should do the trick

Edit :
Sorry late night and not thinking clearly. Split your print line into an if check. If you cheese is "" print line without the cheese bit and else print the line you have now.

Sorry for not providing code example, posting from my phone, shouldn't do that I suppose

Comment: I want to remove the "and cheese" if there isnt any cheese. It still appeared "... and cheese."

Answer (score 0):

one easy way is:

```
def sandwich(bread, meat='turkey', cheese=None):
    print bread,"bread sandwich with",meat,      
    if cheese:
        print "and",cheese,"cheese"
```